# pandas groupby freq 5s

Tags: python, pandas, network-traffic

I load a .csv with network traffic, and I put the time like index. I count by the group of "ipdst proto and time".

```
...
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.index = df['time']
data = df.copy()

data_group = pd.DataFrame({'count': data.groupby(['ipdst', 'proto', data.index]).size()}).reset_index()
data_group
```

Out:

```
ipdst           proto   time                   count
10.3.20.102     HTTP    2017-03-20 17:08:56     1
10.3.20.102     HTTP    2017-03-20 17:08:57     1
10.3.20.102     HTTP    2017-03-20 17:08:58     1
10.3.20.102     HTTP    2017-03-20 17:08:58     1
10.3.20.102     TCP     2017-03-20 17:08:59     3
```

Now I want see what "ipdst" and "protocol" are repeated in time frequency of 5s. Like the next out:

```
  ipdst       proto  time                 count     
    -           -    2017-03-20 17:08:50    0
10.3.20.102    HTTP  2017-03-20 17:08:55    4
10.3.20.102    TCP   2017-03-20 17:08:55    4
    -           -    2017-03-20 17:09:00    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use `groupby`, `resample`, `sum` and `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(['ipdst','proto']).resample('5S', on='time').sum().reset_index()
```

OR (if you are using older Pandas before 0.19.0)

```
df.set_index('time').groupby(['ipdst','proto']).resample('5S').sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         ipdst proto                time  count
0  10.3.20.102  HTTP 2017-03-20 17:08:55      4
1  10.3.20.102   TCP 2017-03-20 17:08:55      3
```

Or you can use pd.Grouper as Wen suggests.  [pd.TimeGrouper is deprecated.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16747)

```
df.groupby([df['ipdst'],df['proto'],pd.Grouper(key='‌​time', freq='5s')])['count'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: I have following error : TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  `on` parameter new in Version 0.19.0

Comment: Got it , thank you , i have not updated my pandas for a long time

Comment: you *might* (not sure) need to `.set_index('time')` before `.ressample(...) for the second version to work